# RANKX DAX not updating other graph

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I've got the following DAX Measure that provides me with the ability to filter down to the last XX of activity from an individual.
I can only seem to add the measure to the Filter on Visual so when chosing to filter down on say the last 10 this does not update other visuals in the report.

What can I do so that I am able to view the last 10 activities, but for the other visuals to update?

```
Rank = RANKX
(ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[Name]),
CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[Date])),,
DESC)
```

[image: Example]

[image: Filter on visual]

Comment: Have you check the interaction of filters between visuals? How are you filtering the top 10? Can you provide the DAX calculation?

Comment: I have edited my question to show the filter on the visual. I can only apply the Rank Measure to Filters on Visual option as when I try to apply to anywhere else it does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you are applying that filter to only one visual.
It's better to implement the logic in the DAX calculation.

### DAX Calculation

```
Rank =
VAR _Calc =
    RANKX (
        ALLEXCEPT ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Name] ),
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( Sheet1[Date] ) ),
        ,
        DESC
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _Calc <= 10, _Calc )
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for what I’m needing. What the Dax is doing is calculating the number of fields which is 15, then by filtering on the visual as shown in my OP will then show the last 10 activity by date.     What I then need is when I filter on this visual, I need it to update the rest to reflect.